# How to set up FreeNAS to use mirrored vdevs?

Tags: nas, storage, home-server, zfs, freenas

I'm setting up a home-use FreeNAS - storage of photos, media, laptop backups and so forth for a pair of users and half a dozen laptops, phones, tablets. I have 4x 3TB drives. I'm deciding on the drive/zpool topology.

[This blog post](http://jrs-s.net/2015/02/06/zfs-you-should-use-mirror-vdevs-not-raidz/) makes a (to me) set of convincing arguments for using mirror vdevs instead of raidz.

I believe I would like:

- 2 vdevs of 2 drives each
- drives mirrored in each vdev
- 1 zpool containing both vdevs

**My question** - how do I set that up within FreeNAS? Is it possible via the GUI (and if so, how?), or do I need to drop down to the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as with other vdev types. The [FreeNAS documentation](http://doc.freenas.org/9.10/freenas_storage.html) explains how it is done, see figure and table 8.1a for details. Note that only available disks will be shown and they limit the possible configurations, so make sure that all your disks are properly recognized.

If it does not work this way, you could also create a striped pool out of two single disk vdevs and then immediately attach a disk to each vdev (resilvering will be nearly instantaneous).

You can also do it in the shell, but I would try with the GUI first.

Comment: The missing part was that the GUI allows one to drag out a 2x2 grid of drives which is what I want - 2x mirrored vdevs each with 2x drives. It wasn't obvious to me.